# Looping with error handling

Tags: python, error-handling

I want to see if a file already exists, and if it does, I want to make a file with an extension and a number. I tried to do this with error handling, but I would have to write out the code 50 times.

Here is the code:

```
for x in range(50):
po = 1
try:
    os.makedirs(acct)
except OSError, e:
    try:
        os.makedirs(acct + "-"+str(po))
        po +=1
    except OSError, e:
        print "Something is broken! Line 14-15"
```

If acct = "me" and the files "me" and "me-1" exist, running the program simply prints the line a bunch of times.

Thank you for all your help!

EDIT:
I changed the code to

```
for po in range(0,5):
try:
    os.makedirs(acct)
except OSError, e:
    try:
        os.makedirs(acct + "-"+str(po))
        break
    except OSError, E:
        print "A weird error popped up. Terminating."
        break
```

For some reason, this creates 2 folders when run.

Comment: what is `acct`? Also your indentation may need fixing.

Comment: Remove `po=1`, and `po+=1`  change `for` to `for po in range(1, 51):`

Comment: acct is a var created by a raw_input

Comment: Stephen, I did that and it created 50 folders. How would I only create 1 folder?

Comment: Why you need the os.makedirs(acct)  inside the loop body???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

The looping at the top created as many as there were. You must specify how many times you want to try and resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the break you will be fine!

```
for po in range(0,5):
    try:
        os.makedirs(acct)
    except OSError:
        try:
            os.makedirs(acct + "-"+str(po))
        except OSError:
            print ("A weird error popped up. Terminating.")
            break
```

Comment: This creates all the possible files :( Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help! Accept my answer or upvote it, if helped. :)